# JavaScript regex does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement the following regex.

It consists of **local** part and **domain** part.

**local** part can be 1 to 64 symbols long. It can contain characters, digits or other symbols. Here is how I take it into account in regex:

```
([!$&*=^`|~#%'+/?_{}\-\.\d]){1,64}
```

(`\d` for digits and `\.` for characters).

**domain** part can be 1 to 253 symbols long. It also can contain characters, digits and other symbols. So, here is how I represent it in regex:

```
([!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-\.\d]){1,253}
```

Between **local** and **domain** parts I need to have a `@` symbol.

So, here is my full regex.

```
const regC = /^([!$&*=^`|~#%'+/?_{}\-\.\d]){1,64}@([!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-\.\d]){1,253}$/;
```

According to the description I provided above I would expect the regex to return true in the following case:

```
regC.test("email@gmail.com");
```

But it returns false. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `\w` in your characters groups ?

Comment: *"(`\d` for digits and `\.` for characters)."* No, `\.` is for a literal dot. For characters, as @Axnyff said, you'd use `\w` (for an English-centric definition, which would probably be incorrect) or `\w` plus a LOT of non-English characters, or [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com) with a Posix class. (JavaScript's regular expressions got Posix classes very recently, but support in JavaScript engines is still quite poor.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, that solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You can add your comment as an answer, so the question can be marked answered, and you get the proper credits :)

Comment: @Philip - For me, this question can just be closed and deleted. `\w` is already well-covered on SO, and this seemed like a typo-level thing ("not likely to be useful to future readers").